# C# Building Permutations with replacement but skip if it doesn't exist in a position

Tags: c#, permutation

I want to permute with replacement but skip if a symbol is not in the list.
Currently the implementation does not rely on PayDistribution.
it uses only the symbol list.
So, if I send the symbolList of (A,B,C) and windowWidth of 3, I will get:

A,A,A

A,A,B

A,A,C

A,B,A

A,B,B

...

C,C,C

But if for example I have a PayDistribution of:

symbol: first to third positions

A:1  1  1

B:1  1  0

C:1  1  1

Where B will not be in the third position, then I don't want to include any permutations where B is in the third position:

A,A,B for example should not exist.

I just want it to jump the the next valid entry.
Seems I can add a check in the GetCombinations function to do so, but I am not sure how.
Really looking to speed this up by skipping.  With large symbolLists it can take a while.
My usage isn't super important:

```
public ACombo[] PayHashLineCreate(SymbolList symbolList, ComboList comboTable, int windowWidth,List<List<int>> PayDistribution)
{
    Console.Write("Creating Pay Hash ");
    WindowWidth = windowWidth;
    SymbolCount = symbolList.NumRegularSym;

    var count = 0;

    var filteredList = new SymbolList();
    
    filteredList.AddRange(symbolList.Where(symbol => typeof (RegularSymbol) == symbol.GetType()));
    filteredList.AddRange(symbolList.Where(symbol => typeof (ScatterSymbol) == symbol.GetType()));
    var filteredSymbolListArray = filteredList.ToArray();

    var filteredComboList = new ComboList();
    filteredComboList.AddRange(comboTable.Where(combo => typeof (T) == combo.GetType()));

    foreach (
        var symbolArrangement in        
  CombinationsWithReplacement.GetCombinationsWithReplacementLexographicOrder(filteredSymbolListArray, windowWidth,PayDistribution))
    {
        Add(null);
        foreach (var combo in filteredComboList)
        {
            var match = Compare(combo, symbolArrangement);
            if (!match) continue;
            this[count] = combo;

            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("DONE");
    return ToArray(); 
}
```

But the important functions:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetCombinationsWithReplacementLexographicOrder<T>(IList<T> pool, 
int comboLength, List<List<int>> PayDistribution)
{
    
    foreach (var list in GetCombinations(pool, comboLength, PayDistribution).Select(c => 
c.ToList()))
    yield return list;
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(IList<T> list, int length, 
List<List<int>> PayDistribution)
{
            
    if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new[] { t });

    return GetCombinations(list, length -1).SelectMany(t => list, (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new[] { t2 
}));
}
```

Comment: I would suggest converting `PayDistribution` to `Dictionary<T, List<int>>` so you can lookup distribution by symbol. I don't see what `GetCombinationsWithReplacementLexographicOrder` adds?

Comment: Your `GetCombinations` method does not compile. Also, changing your code to compile seems to indicate an off by one error in `length` / `windowWidth`.

Comment: @NetMage I added count, thinking I could build the combination the other way as to reference the Paydistribution in the correct order.  I have removed it and it is back to the way it was.  You were right, it would crash.

Comment: @NetMage What would the function look like if PayDistribution was a Dictionary?  Seems easy enough to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `PayDistribution` is position first, then symbol, it can be directly converted to a `Dictionary` for each `T` and filter the combinations by the matching `Dictionary` for each position:

```
private static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetCombinationsWithReplacementLexographicOrder<T>(IList<T> list, int length, List<List<int>> PayDistribution) {
    var PayMap = PayDistribution.Select(g => g.Select((pd,i) => (pd,i)).ToDictionary(pdi => list[pdi.i], pdi => pdi.pd > 0)).ToList();

    foreach (var c in GetCombinations(list, length, PayMap))
        yield return c.ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(IList<T> list, int length, List<Dictionary<T, bool>> PayMaps, int pos = 1) {
    var payMap = PayMaps[length-pos];
    if (pos == length)
        return list.Where(t => payMap[t]).Select(t => new[] { t });

    return GetCombinations(list, length, PayMaps, pos + 1)
            .SelectMany(t => list.Where(t2 => payMap[t2]), (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new[] { t2 }));
}
```

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do with the PayMaps, but it came out "sideways"  So continuing on my example above,  I think you would expect

A:True  A:True A:True
B:True B:True B:False
C:True C:True C:True

But what it looks like is

A:False B:False C:False
A:False B:False C:False
A:False B:False C:False

And because of this, when I run my code, it does not contain D or E or more further down the line, and everything is false.

Comment: The end result is a crash when the Key is not in the dictionary.

Comment: after you go through the list and pair up the pd with the position i,  you then step through the columns of the PayDistribution list and match it up with the row of the list(variable).  So each column of PayDistribution should have the same entry(row) but it is accessing the column.  So instead of having A across the columns, I get A B C.

Comment: @user3281977 It sounds to me like you should update your question - e.g. given your example code, it isn't possible for there to be a missing key. Given `List<List<int>> PayDistribution` I assumed it matched your example data (so one sub-list for each symbol, each sublist is the positions). If it is opposite, you just remove the `Pivot` call. If you added code to create simulated `PayDistribution` and symbols, so we can replicate your issue, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I have figured out what I need using your code.  I took out the Pivot() call.  That way when you select, it grabs the column and indexes into the list it lines up great.  After you grouped it in the pivot method, the indexing of the columns was off.  then to fix everything being false, I changed the  pdi.pd == 1 to  pdi.pd >0.  Because my entries are false if 0 and can be greater than 1.  But that is my fault with my example everything was 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using @NetMage solution, I just needed to modify it slightly to remove the Pivot() call and change the pdi.pd == 1 to pdi.pd >0.  The count being more than 1 is insignificant in my case.  I just didn't want to create a permutation with 0.
Now the List A,B,C,D or how many I want, will create Permutations With Replacement in windowWidth (length) number of positions unless I send it a double list with 0 in a specific position. thus skipping invalid permutations.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetCombinationsWithReplacementLexographicOrder<T>(IList<T> list, int length, List<List<int>> PayDistribution)
    {

        var PayMap = PayDistribution
            .Select(g => g.Select((pd, i) => (pd, i))
            .ToDictionary(pdi => list[pdi.i], pdi => pdi.pd >0)
            ).ToList();

        foreach (var c in GetCombinations(list, length, PayMap))
            yield return c.ToList();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(IList<T> list, int length, List<Dictionary<T, bool>> PayMaps, int pos = 1)
    {
        var payMap = PayMaps[length - pos];
        if (pos == length)
            return list.Where(t => payMap[t]).Select(t => new[] { t });

        return GetCombinations(list, length, PayMaps, pos + 1)
                .SelectMany(t => list.Where(t2 => payMap[t2]), (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new[] { t2 }));
    }
```